# CodeIgniter Error validation username

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I'm new working with CI, and I have a problem I'm trying to validate a form, it work when i let any field in blank the code show me the validate error and it can save the user in the DB tooh... but the validation save 2 user with the same "usuario"  and I don't want this

if anyone can help with that

this is the code of controller.

```
<?php

class Usuarios extends CI_controller
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();

    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->model('usuarios_model');
  }

  public function index()
  {
    $this->load->view('usuarios_view');
  }

  public function registro()
  {

    $this->load->view('registro_view');
    //$this->load->model('usuarios_model');     
  }

  public function registro_very()
  {
    if($this->input->post('submit_reg'))
    {

      $this->form_validation->set_rules('nombre', 'Nombre', 'required');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('correo', 'Correo', 'required|trim');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('user', 'Usuario', 'required|trim|callback_veryuser');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('pass', 'Contraseña', 'required|trim');

      $this->form_validation->set_message('required', 'El campo %s esobligatorio');
      $this->form_validation->set_message('veryuser', 'El %s ya existe');

      if($this->form_validation->run() != FALSE)
      {
        $this->usuarios_model->add_user();
        $data = array('mensaje' => 'El usuario se registro correctamente');
        $this->load->view('registro_view', $data);
      }
      else
      {
        $this->load->view('registro_view');
      }
    }
  }

  public function veryuser($user)
  {
    $variable = $this->usuarios_model->veryuser($user);
    if($variable == true)
    {
      return false;
    }
    else
    {
      return true;
    }
  }

}
```

Model:

```
class Usuarios_model extends CI_model
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
  }

  public function veryuser($user)
  {
    $consulta = $this->db->get_where('usuarios', array('usuario' => $user));

    $row_cnt = $consulta->num_rows;
    if($row_cnt == 1)
    {

      return true; //el usuario existe
    }
    else
    {
      return false; //el usuario no existe      
    }
  }

  public function add_user()
  {
    $this->db->insert('usuarios',
        array(
        'nombre' => $this->input->post('nombre', true),
        'correo' => $this->input->post('correo', true),
        'usuario' => $this->input->post('user', true),
        'pass' => $this->input->post('pass', true),
        'codigo' => '123456',
        'estado' => '0'
    ));
  }

}
```

And the view

```
<html>
  <body>    
    <h1>Registrar Usuario</h1>  
    <?php if(isset($mensaje)): ?>   
      <h2><?= $mensaje; ?></h2>         
    <?php endif; ?>     

    <form name="form_reg" action="<?= base_url().'usuarios/registro_very' ?>" method="post">

      <label for="Nombre">Nombre</label>        
      <input type="text" name="nombre" value="<?= @set_value('nombre') ?>"><br>

      <label for="Correo">Correo</label>        
      <input type="text" name="correo" value="<?= @set_value('correo') ?>"><br>

      <label for="usuario">usuario</label>      
      <input type="text" name="user" value="<?= @set_value('user') ?>"><br>

      <label for="Contraseña">Contraseña</label>
      <input type="password" name="pass" value="<?= @set_value('pass') ?>"><br>

      <input type="submit" value="Registrar" name="submit_reg"> 
      <a href="<?= base_url().'usuarios/' ?>" title="Iniciar Sesión">Iniciar Sesión</a>     
    </form>     
    <hr>    <?= validation_errors(); ?> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is here on your code following line:

```
$row_cnt = $consulta->num_rows;
```

so you have to replace this :

```
$row_cnt = $consulta->num_rows();
```

or

```
$row_cnt = $consulta->count_all_results
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try debugging veryuser() to check whether it is working or not? Are you setting $user before calling the veryuser()? Try following:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('user', 'Usuario', 'required|trim|callback_veryuser['.$this->input->post('user').']');
```

My suggestion is to read the documentation before posting a question in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

this is a small point and probably not the issue - but if you are testing over and over with the same user name  - in your model - change this

```
  if($row_cnt == 1)
    {

      return true; //el usuario existe
    }
```

thats saying IF there is only one row then return true. but if you did testing before doing the callback there is going to be more then one row with the user name. change it to

```
  if($row_cnt >= 1)
    {

      return true; //el usuario existe
    }
```

otherwise start echoing things out and isolate where the problem is.